# Pymongo Query with Dictionary inside Dictionary?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have Document in MongoDB like this:

```
{"ONE": {"TWO": {"THREE":"5"}}}
```

I want to query mongoDb using the [Pymongo `find` API](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html), but it's not working:

```
for value in dbaccess.find({"ONE":{"TWO":{"THREE":{"$gt":"0"}}}}):
     print value
```

Nothing is getting printed with the above code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two things:

1. If you want to treat the 5 in your document as an integer, don't enclose it in double quotes.
2. Use dot notation for querying nested documents:

   `dbaccess.find("ONE.TWO.THREE": {"$gt": 0})`

Comment: Excellent!!! Thanks a Lot. Another Q....If i want to have sum of all the values.....do we have a way to get it? for example...if i have multiple such document and my goal is to get sum of all ONE.TWO.THREE values....is it possible to get it from pymongo API? can find or any other help me in the same?

Comment: See the group method of a collection as discussed [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=group#pymongo.collection.Collection.group).

Comment: Thank You Once Again. Just One More Q..:-) I have a strange situation ..You suggested to query as "ONE.TWO.THREE" but in some documents the "TWO" can be anything else :-( ....I tried to use reqx and also giving * instead of TWO but didn't work :-(

Comment: And what if I have several items in "TWO"?